# JavaScript script - reading a CSV file into an SVG script

Tags: javascript, regex, csv, constants, fetch-api

I am new to JavaScript, and I'm trying to adapt a script used to display [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG) images.

Currently the script reads the values form within the script, and I want to adapt this to read the values from a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file. The issue I have is the script doesn't seem to interpret the value correctly. The column I'm having issues with is "`nodeStyle`". If I change the column variable from `nodeStyle` to `{width:100, height:100}` it works, but it won’t read it from the CSV file. How can I fix this?

// Data.CSV format 
// id, x, y, href, nodeStyleW,nodeStyle,properties,label_text 
// NODE22,650,50,/icon.png,{width:100,height:100},,NODE22

```
   fetch('/data.csv')
     .then(response => response.text())
     .then(data => {

       const rows = data.split('\n').slice(1); // Skip header row
         rows.forEach(row => {
           const [id, x, y, href, nodeStyle, properties, label_text] = row.split(/,(?![^{]*})/);

           net.addNode(id, parseInt(x), parseInt(y), href, nodeStyle, properties, label_text);
         });
     });

   // Mode added via script
   net.addNode("NODE2", 600, 50, "/images/icon.png", {width: 100, height: 100}, "", "", "NODE2");
```

I have tried adding the value directly and this works:

```
net.addNode(id, parseInt(x), parseInt(y), href, nodeStyle, properties, label_text);
net.addNode(id, parseInt(x), parseInt(y), href, {width: 100, height:100}, properties, label_text);
```

Answer (score -1):

Resolved: Changing the code fixed the issue. I just needed to amend the CSV file to `{"width": 100, "height": 100}`.